# How do I bind to the parent's DataContext in a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a situation in which I am using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in which most display fields are bound to the items represented in this template (like you'd expect), but I also need one `Binding` to the data context of the `UserControl` itself. I fail to manage this last bit.

So I currently have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.ProjectTreeView">

<UserControl.Resources>    
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type StreetViewModel}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Houses}">   

        <!-- This Binding works fine (binds to local:StreetViewModel.Street.StreetName) -->             
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street.StreetName}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                         <!-- THIS BINDING DOESN'T WORK (I want it to bind to local:ProjectTreeView.SelectedStreet) -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedStreet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Main Street">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <!-- This one works again (binds to local:StreetViewModel.Street.ConstructionWorkGoingOn) -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Street.ConstructionWorkGoingOn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </TextBlock.Style>
       </TextBlock>
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

So the problematic thing is that I want to access data in `ProjectTreeView` but can't reach it within this code. I've tried all sort of things with `RelativeSource` but that doesn't work. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try RelativeSource binding with AncestorType UserControl? `{Binding Path=SelectedStreet, RelativeSource=RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Almost, for some reason it still needs `...Path=DataContext.SelectedStreet...`, and then it works (see answer by @eran otzap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedStreet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Main Street">
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
   </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Is it possible that suddenly the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` doesn't work any more this way? It seems like it works once, but then when firing `PropertyChanged` events, it doesn't respond...

Comment: it shouldn't effect the UpdateSourceTrigger

Comment: Did you find out what was the "weird thing going on"?