# How can I bind to the View's DataContext and not the innermost DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

Some pseudo-code to serve as an example:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SomeOtherContext}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" />
            <Grid DataContext="THE FIRST CONTEXT">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyFromFirstContext}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So, what I am looking for is the binding syntax necessary in place of "**THE FIRST CONTEXT**" to make the innermost `TextBlock` binding pull its property from the outermost `DataContext`, and not the one set at the intermediate `StackPanel`.

I've found examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792926/how-do-i-bind-to-the-parents-datacontext-in-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate) that suggest a way of doing it in the `TextBlock` binding, but if I had a mass of controls in there, that's a lot of extra coding.  I would rather set a new `DataContext` at that particular scope so that the inner binding syntax is cleaner to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Parent">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SomeOtherContext}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" />
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Parent}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyFromFirstContext}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Is SomeOtherContext a property of MyViewModel ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It's actually an instance of a data Model.

Comment: This actually works fine. Make sure all the properties are initialized and there are no binding errors in the output when you run your application.

Comment: Your suspicion seems correct...there was an error being thrown on an unrelated binding that I had not yet noticed.  Fixing that enabled this reference to work properly. Thank you.